# sqlite regex: How return count of 'X' from values in column

Tags: regex, sqlite, pandasql

i am using pandasql to transform data. Inside a query i would like to pull out for example the number of periods ('.') in the email address. SQLite does not seem to support regex.

In SQL i could write:

```
length(regexp_replace(email, '[^.]', '', 'g')) as email_period

*#applying this to the email (my.first_name@abc.com) would return 2*
```

Look forward to your expertise for a solution with SQLite. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simple `REPLACE` and `LENGTH` to calculate number of periods:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(email VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO tab(email) 
VALUES ('my.first_name@abc.com'),('my.first.name@abc.com.ru');

SELECT email, LENGTH(email) - LENGTH(REPLACE(email, '.', '')) AS  email_period
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/eed94/1/0)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

Counting digits:

```
SELECT email,
   LENGTH(email) - 
   LENGTH(REPLACE( REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
             REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(email, '0', '')
             ,'1', ''),'2', ''),'3', ''),'4', '')  
             ,'5', ''),'6', ''),'7', ''),'8', '')  
             ,'9', '')) AS email_digits
FROM tab
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/3cbd2/2/0)**</kbd>

Comment: Well done, thank you! What about counting the number of integers in the email? Is there a simpler way other than taking same approach with periods and applying it to each individual integer (i.e. 0-9, therefore 10 queries) and then summing results from all queries?